# Official T460s Ubuntu support

Tags: 14.10, lenovo

Does anyone know if the the T460s will eventually have official support, like the T450s? Or would that have happen already?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 is not supported anymore, but my T560 runs fine with 16.04.

Comment: What about 14.04?

Comment: Using Ubuntu 15.10 and having installed Ubuntu extras, everything appears to work except two things: 1) freezes after closing lid and re-opening it, 2) freezes when plugging in anything to HDMI or Display Port.

Comment: I have T560 with 16.06 and I also have the same two problems: 1. freezes after closing lid **on battery**, 2. freezes plugging in second monitor on HDMI.

Comment: The "lid close freezes the system" bug is fixed on Wily now, and fixes are queued for Vivid and Xenial. https://bugs.launchpad.net/intel/+bug/1559923

Comment: Looks like this laptop has been awarded the status of certified pre-install for Ubuntu (https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201512-20435/). So I suppose Ubuntu is working flawlessly on it.

Answer (score 4):

I tried Lenovo T460 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 15.10, and 16.04 Beta 2 and they all had two issues:

1. Using an external monitor would freeze the system. (I tried many combinations, e.g. plug-in then turn on, plug-in at login screen, different cables, etc)
2. Closing the lid would cause the system to freeze and not go to sleep.

After updating to linux kernel 4.5 you can attach an HDMI monitor, but mini Display Port (mDP) will still cause the system to freeze, and closing the lid still causes the system to freeze.

Important related notes:

- You have to boot the system with the HDMI monitor attached. Only then can you plug and unplug the monitor without the system freezing.
- If you have Intel Virtualization Technology and Intel VT-d Feature enabled under "Security" in the bios (e.g. for use with VirtualBox), you cannot plug in an external display or the system will freeze.
- I tried Fedora 23 and Linux Mint 17.3, both with similar problems described above with Ubuntu.
- I am currently using Fedora 24 and find it to be the most stable. I still can't use mDP and can't put it to sleep without a crash, but I can at least plug-in and remove HDMI while booted.

See also this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/49oelo/t460_pro_dock_ubuntu_freeze_with_dp_monitor/) for a conversation regarding Ubuntu and displays with the T460

Comment: Lid close used to crash the system for me, but I and others see this as fixed now.

Comment: How did you install the 4.5 kernel? Can I get it via xenial-proposed, or must it be done manually?

Comment: Just noticed the link to Kernel/Mainlinebuilds in the Reddit thread...

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 16.04 LTS. Upgraded bios to 1.11 and installed kernel 4.5.2-040502-generic. HDMI works, and yesterday it worked all day long. Today, however, it freezes all the time. The last thing I see in the kernel logs is this: http://pastebin.com/qpTJU9Bu

Edit: with kernel 4.6 hdmi seems stable for me. What I did:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p /tmp/kernel46 && cd /tmp/kernel46
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Your answer does not seem to answer the OPs question. Please be specific to the question.

Comment: I fully agree. Forgot myself when fiddling with this and treated it as a forum post. Out of curiosity: The other answer does not answer The OPs question either, so why is my answer (rightly) downvoted, but not that answer?